# How prove $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{17}) + \cos(\frac{18\pi}{17})+\cos(\frac{26\pi}{17})+\cos(\frac{30\pi}{17}) = \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{17}) + \cos(\frac{18\pi}{17})+\cos(\frac{26\pi}{17})+\cos(\frac{30\pi}{17}) = \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{4}$

Regards that value of [$\cos(2\pi/17)$](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-that-cos-left-frac-2-pi-17-right-frac-1+-sqrt-17-+-sqrt-34-2-sqrt-17-+2-sqrt-17+3-sqrt-17-sqrt-34-2-sqrt-17-2-sqrt-34+2-sqrt-17-16#FYKGJ), I can't find the easy way to solve that expression.

Even if I had time, I wouldn't try that method to find the all roots others cosines expressions. IMHO

Comment: The quadratic Gauss sum?

Comment: Cool!  We're constructing the regular 17-gon!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717536/proving-that-cos-frac2-pi13-cos-frac6-pi13-cos-frac8-pi13-frac

Comment: @OscarLanzi how so?

Comment: This is a step in that construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Then
$$g_p=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\exp(2\pi i k^2/p)$$
is a *quadratic Gauss sum*. Gauss proved that $g_p=\sqrt p$ or
$i\sqrt p$ according to whether $p\equiv1$ or $p\equiv3\pmod 4$.
It is quite easy to prove this up to sign, but hard to prove the sign.

So $g_{17}=\sqrt{17}$. Therefore
\begin{align}
\sqrt{17}&=1+2\exp(2\pi i/17)+2\exp(8\pi i/17)+2\exp(18\pi i/17)
+2\exp(32\pi i/17)\\
&+2\exp(16\pi i/17)+2\exp(4\pi i/17)+2\exp(30\pi i/17)
+2\exp(26\pi i/17)\\
&=1+4\cos(2\pi/17)+4\cos(18\pi/17)+4\cos(26\pi/17)+4\cos(30\pi/17).
\end{align}

Comment: Where does the constant 2 (in all those terms) come from that sum?

Comment: He folded the terms together using the periodicity of the cosine function.  Example: $15^2\equiv 2^2 \bmod 17$ because $(15+2)|(15^2-2^2)$, thus $\cos(2^2×(2\pi/17))+\cos(15^2×(2\pi/17))=2\cos(2^2×(2\pi/17))$.

Comment: Last question. How can you cancel the $\sin$ component into the exponential complex on the last step?

Comment: @miguel747 $2\cos x=\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix)$.