# Simplifying $\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{21}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{8 \pi}{21}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{21}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Given
>   $$ S = \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{21}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{8 \pi}{21}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{21}\right)$$
>   then what are some, or at least one, method to reduce this sum?
>   According to Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica $$S = \frac{1 + \sqrt{21}}{4}.$$

**Attempt**

By using 
\begin{align}
(a + b + c)^3 &= 6 a b c + 3 (a + b + c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) - 2 (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) \\
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 &= (a + b + c)^2 - 2 (ab + bc + ca) \\
\cos^3 \theta &= \frac{1}{4} \, ( 3 \cos\theta + \cos(3 \theta))
\end{align}
or
$$ (a + b + c)^3 = (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) - 3 (a + b + c)(ab + bc + ca) - 3 a b c$$
then
$$(\cos x + \cos y + \cos z)^3 - \frac{3}{4} (\cos x + \cos y + \cos z) = \frac{1}{4} (\cos 3x + \cos 3y + \cos 3z) - 3 (\cos x + \cos y + \cos z) (\cos x \cos y + \cos y \cos z + \cos z \cos x) - 3 \cos x \cos y \cos z.$$
If 
$$ x = \frac{2 \pi}{21} \quad y = \frac{8 \pi}{21} \quad z = \frac{10 \pi}{21}$$
then
$$S^3 - \frac{3}{4} \, S = \frac{x}{4} - 3 S \, P - 3 \, \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{21}\right) \cos\left(\frac{8 \pi}{21}\right) \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{21}\right), $$
where 
\begin{align}
x &= \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{8 \pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{7}\right) \\
&= - \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{3 \pi}{7}\right) \right) \\
P &= \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{21}\right) \cos\left(\frac{8 \pi}{21}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{8 \pi}{21}\right) \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{21}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{21}\right) \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{21}\right). 
\end{align}

Since, 
\begin{align}
P &= \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{21}\right) \cos\left(\frac{8 \pi}{21}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{8 \pi}{21}\right) \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{21}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{21}\right) \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{21}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \left[ \left(\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{4 \pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{6 \pi}{7}\right) \right) +  \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{21}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{8 \pi}{21}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{21}\right)  \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \left[ S - \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{3 \pi}{7}\right) \right) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, (S + x),
\end{align}
then 
$$S^3 + \frac{3}{2} \, S^2 - \frac{3}{4} \, S = \frac{x}{4} - \frac{3 \, x \, S}{4} - 3 \, \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi}{21}\right) \cos\left(\frac{8 \pi}{21}\right) \cos\left(\frac{10 \pi}{21}\right).$$

This seems to be trading one complication for another.

**Note** 
The original problem was related to a reduction of
$$x = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{4 \pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{5 \pi}{7}\right)$$
but was in error since, in my notes, I had made a reduction of $\frac{2}{3}$ to each term.

Comment: There seems to be no [obvious best simplification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28pi%2F7%29+%2B+cos%284*pi%2F7%29+%2B+cos%285*pi%2F7%29). Can you tell us what exactly you're trying to do with this sum?

Comment: error in the original problem, must be $$ x = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{3 \pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{5 \pi}{7}\right)$$

Comment: Maybe not. It is hard, no doubt. Could be useful this I have deduced: $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{21}\right)=1-2\cos^2\left(\frac{10\pi}{21}\right)?$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717536/proving-that-cos-frac2-pi13-cos-frac6-pi13-cos-frac8-pi13-frac  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2756031/how-prove-cos-frac2-pi17-cos-frac18-pi17-cos-frac26-pi17  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381294/how-to-prove-an-identity-trigonometry-angles-pi-13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a = \frac\pi{21}$ and

$$ S = \cos2a + \cos 8a+\cos10a, \>\>\>\>\> T= \cos4a + \cos 16a+\cos20a$$

Use the trig identity $2\cos x\cos y = \cos(x-y)+\cos(x+y)$ to get
$$2\cos\frac\pi3(\cos\frac\pi7+\cos\frac{3\pi}7+\cos\frac{5\pi}7)=S+T$$

Knowing $\cos\frac\pi7+\cos\frac{3\pi}7+\cos\frac{5\pi}7=\frac12$, we have

$$S+T= \frac12\tag 1$$
Use the trig identity again to evaluate
$$\begin{align}
2ST &=2( \cos2a + \cos 8a+\cos10a)(\cos4a + \cos 16a+\cos20a) \\
& = S+T + 3(\cos6a+\cos12a+\cos14a+\cos18a) \\
& = \frac12 +3\cos\frac{2\pi}3- 3(\cos\frac\pi7+\cos\frac{3\pi}7+\cos\frac{5\pi}7) \\
& = \frac12 -\frac32 -\frac32 = -\frac52 \\
\end{align}$$

So,

$$ST = -\frac54\tag 2$$

From (1) and (2), $S$ and $T$ satisfy the quadratic equation,

$$x^2-\frac12x-\frac54=0$$

which yields

$$S = \frac{1+\sqrt{21}}4$$

Comment: @Leucippus - Revised the answer accordingly.

Comment: Much easier than I made it into.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the problem was intended to be 
$$ x = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{3 \pi}{7}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{5 \pi}{7}\right)$$
because this one really does simplify.

Take $$ \omega = e^{2 \pi i / 7} $$
so that $\omega^7 = 1$ and $\omega \neq 1$ and
$$ 1 + \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^3 + \omega^4 + \omega^5 + \omega^6 = 0. $$
Well, as pointed out by Gauss, take
$$ \alpha = \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^4  $$
so that $$ \alpha + \bar{\alpha } = -1.  $$
Since $\omega^8 = \omega,$ we find
$$  \alpha^2 = \omega^2 + \omega^4 + \omega^8 + 2 \omega^3 + 2 \omega^5 + 2 \omega^6,  $$
$$ \alpha^2 + \alpha = 2( \omega + \omega^2 + \omega^3 + \omega^4 + \omega^5 + \omega^6  )  $$
$$ \alpha^2 + \alpha + 2 = 0 $$
so that $$ \alpha = \frac{-1 \pm i \sqrt 7}{2} $$
Meanwhile,
$$ \alpha = \left( \cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} + \cos \frac{4 \pi}{7} + \cos \frac{8 \pi}{7} \right)+  i \left( \sin \frac{2 \pi}{7} + \sin \frac{4 \pi}{7} + \sin \frac{8 \pi}{7} \right)$$

$$  \cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} + \cos \frac{4 \pi}{7} + \cos \frac{8 \pi}{7} =- \frac{1}{2}$$
$$ - \cos \frac{5 \pi}{7} - \cos \frac{3 \pi}{7} - \cos \frac{ \pi}{7} = - \frac{1}{2}$$
$$  \cos \frac{5 \pi}{7} + \cos \frac{3 \pi}{7} + \cos \frac{ \pi}{7} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

About your new problem with the 21's.

Here is a modern presentation, two chapters [about the Gauss method, book by Cox.](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf)

If $\omega$ is a primitive 21st root of unity, and we take
$$ \alpha = \omega + \omega^4 + \omega^{16} \; , \; $$
we find that
$$  \alpha^4 - \alpha^3 - \alpha^2 - 2 \alpha + 4 = 0.  $$
See [page 202 in Reuschle(1875)](https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false). 
This polynomial is irreducible over the rationals, but factors as
$$ \left( x^2 - \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{21}}{2} \right) x + 2 \right) \left( x^2 - \left( \frac{1 - \sqrt{21}}{2} \right) x + 2 \right) $$

[image]

Comment: Bravo! And thank you very much for making me rest. I wanted to solve the problem and I was not going to rest and perhaps I would try without achieving anything.

Comment: @Piquito thanks. The entire Reuschle book is on that web page. I was able to order a paperback reprint for very little money. I recommend it for anyone answering questions on MSE. When a question can be answered with Gausses cyclotomic method, that is typically the most illuminating way to work it.

Comment: I allow myself to tell you what I was doing (you know how appreciated is elementary where the topic is not). In the attached figure, $\angle{CAP}= 8t$ so $\cos(10t)=\dfrac{\cos(2t)}{\overline{AP}}$. By the comment I deduced above I get $\overline{AP}^2=\dfrac{2\cos^2(2t)}{1-\cos(t)}$ so the segment $x=\overline{CP}$ is determined and also $\cos(8t)$ for the triangle $\triangle CAP$. In sum I can get a fonction $$S=f(\cos(2t),\cos(t))$$ but I don't know if $f$ was going to be complicated. Anyway I have left the problem. Thanks for your attention.I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- I apologize for the attached figure to ilustrated a comment above.

[image]